# Is the remove method from my Circular Linked List well defined?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I'm building a circular linked list, and I would like to know if the `do_remove` method is well defined. When I run the program, it shows me that it is, however, I'm still a bit confused why I don't need a virtual destrutor in this case.

Is the virtual destructor only needed when I want to destroy a derived class through it's base pointer?

Does this mean that by downcasting a base class to a derived class, and then calling the derived class destructor, it will always call the base class destructor?

Can there be possible leaks in the `do_remove` method?

PS: I need the object creation and destruction to be a two step process - allocation / call to constructor / call to destructor / deallocation; that's why I'm using `::operator new` for the time being.

Here's a self contained example of the code I'm writing:

```
#include <iostream>

struct NodeBase {
    NodeBase * previous;
    NodeBase * next;

    NodeBase() noexcept
    : previous(this)
    , next(this) {
    }

    NodeBase(NodeBase * const previous, NodeBase * const next) noexcept
    : previous(previous)
    , next(next) {
    }

    ~NodeBase() {
        std::puts("~NodeBase()");
    }
};

template <typename TYPE>
struct Node : NodeBase {
    TYPE data;

    template <typename ...ARGUMENTS>
    Node(NodeBase * const previous, NodeBase * const next, ARGUMENTS && ...arguments)
    : NodeBase(previous, next)
    , data(std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...) {
        previous->next = this;
        next->previous = this;
    }

    ~Node() {
        std::puts("~Node()");
    }
};

template <typename TYPE>
class List {
    using Node = Node<TYPE>;

    int64_t this_length;
    NodeBase this_sentinel;

    Node * as_node(NodeBase * const input) noexcept {
        return static_cast<Node * const>(input);
    }

    Node const * as_node(NodeBase const * const input) const noexcept {
        return static_cast<Node const * const>(input);
    }

    template <typename ...ARGUMENTS>
    List & do_insert(NodeBase * const node, ARGUMENTS && ...arguments) {
        void * const address = ::operator new(sizeof(Node));
        try {
            new (address) Node(node->previous, node, std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...);
            ++this_length;
            return *this;
        } catch (...) {
            ::operator delete(address);
            throw;
        }
    }

    // Is this method well defined?
    List & do_remove(NodeBase * input) noexcept {
        Node * const node = as_node(input);
        input->previous->next = input->next;
        input->next->previous = input->previous;
        node->~Node();
        ::operator delete(node);
        --this_length;
        return *this;
    }

public:
    List()
    : this_length(0)
    , this_sentinel() {
    }

    ~List() {
        std::puts("~List()");
        while (this_length) {
            pop();
        }
    }

    TYPE & head() noexcept {
        return as_node(this_sentinel.next)->data;
    }

    TYPE const & head() const noexcept {
        return as_node(this_sentinel.next)->data;
    }

    TYPE & last() noexcept {
        return as_node(this_sentinel.previous)->data;
    }

    TYPE const & last() const noexcept {
        return as_node(this_sentinel.previous)->data;
    }

    template <typename ...ARGUMENTS>
    List & push(ARGUMENTS && ...arguments) {
        return do_insert(this_sentinel.next, std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...);
    }

    List & pop() noexcept {
        return do_remove(this_sentinel.next);
    }
};

int main() {

    List<int> list;

    list.push(5).push(7).push(3);

    std::cout << list.head() << std::endl;
    std::cout << list.last() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the virtual destructor only needed when I want to destroy a derived
>   class through it's base pointer?

Yes. Only if you delete object using base pointer (or if you manage it using `unique_ptr` to base) you need virtual destructor in base. Other cases like deleting pointer to most derived type or managing with 'shared_ptr' to base do not need virtual destructor.

> Does this mean that by downcasting a base class to a derived class,
>   and then calling the derived class destructor, it will always call the
>   base class destructor?

Yes. Destructor of derived class is required to call destructors of (base and member) sub-objects.

> Can there be possible leaks in the do_remove method?

No, if the destructor of TYPE does not leak. For simplicity it would be better to use ordinary delete expression

```
    delete node;
```

instead of writing out what it is anyway required to do

```
    node->~Node();
    ::operator delete(node);
```

Comment: I'm planning on making a specialized node allocator, that's why I'm separating destruction and deallocation. It makes it easier to later change the code to accomodate the new allocator. Thanks :)